# Derivative of Negative Exponent

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Could you explain to me why the derivative with respect to y of the function below: $$\frac{-n}{{y^{n+1}}}\:$$
is: $$\frac{n{(n+1)}}{{y^{n+2}}}\:$$

I specifically do not understand (n+1) in the numerator.

Comment: What is the derivative of $y^{-n-1}$?

Comment: $${{-ny^{-n-2}}}\:$$

Comment: No, it's $(-n-1)y^{-n-2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\forall n\in R$, if $f(y)=y^n$, it’s derivative is $f’(y)=ny^{n-1}$, so $$\left(\frac{-n}{y^{n+1}}\right)’=\left(-ny^{-(n+1)}\right)’=(-n)(-(n+1))y^{-(n+1)-1}=\frac{n(n+1)}{y^{n+2}}$$